# What is the reading order for books in Peter F. Hamilton's Confederation Universe?

Tags: suggested-order, nights-dawn-trilogy

I want to read this series from the beginning. Just looking at his [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_F._Hamilton), it looks like all of his books follow their publishing date, but I was wondering if anyone out there that has read them can comment on the exact reading order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You read the "The Night's Dawn Trilogy" in the order there

The "Others in the Confederation Universe" are orthogonal and don't relate to the plot of Night's Dawn. They do provide background though: I'd read them after because your curiosity is piqued...

Comment: While this is mostly true, the exception is "A Second Chance at Eden" (not the entire short story collection, but the story of the same name contained within). I find it makes for a nice introduction to several key concepts in the trilogy.